# 'EOFError: end of file reached' on HEROKU while posting UTF-8 via SSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, https

I've got strange bug on heroku. To reproduce it I have to make big (over few KB) HTTPS POST with any UTF-8 characters in request body. Here is an example:

```
require "net/https"
require "uri"

#Accutally I've ecountered this bug while posting to another server
url = URI.parse("https://api.heroku.com/myapps")

#It's Ukrainian 'oiced velar plosive G' letter
payload = "ґ"*10000
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url.path)
request.body = payload
http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.read_timeout = 500
http.start {|http| http.request request }
```

Running such script on local machine's irb gives me:

```
#<Net::HTTPUnauthorized 401 Unauthorized readbody=true>
```

...which is expected, but on heroku cedar, runing it on 'heroku console' ... in about 60sec I get:

```
EOFError: end of file reached
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/buffering.rb:145:in `sysread_nonblock'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/buffering.rb:145:in `read_nonblock'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:135:in `rbuf_fill'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:116:in `readuntil'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:126:in `readline'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2219:in `read_status_line'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2208:in `read_new'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1191:in `transport_request'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1177:in `request'
    from (irb):32:in `block in irb_binding'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:627:in `start'
    from (irb):32
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
```

What should I do with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to add ruby version into **Gemfile**, as default Cedar's ruby is 1.9.2(which has bug passing UTF-8 strings over SSL)

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "1.9.3"

gem 'rails', '3.2.7'
gem 'pg'
...
```

Answer (score 2):

I think, this should works:

```
require "net/https"
require "uri"

url = URI.parse("https://api.heroku.com/myapps")
#It's Ukrainian letter 'soft-G'
payload = "ґ"*10000
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url.path)
request.basic_auth 'youremail', 'yourpassword'
request.body = URI.encode(payload)
http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.read_timeout = 500
http.start {|http| http.request request }
```